# How to do a like case-insensitive and accent insensitive in PostgreSQL and JPA 2?

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, postgresql-9.1

I have a Java EE project using PostgreSQL 9.X and JPA2 (Hibernate implementation).
How can I force a like query to be case insensitive and accent insensitive?

I'm able to change the charset of the DB because it's the first project using it.

Comment: Are you using Criteria queries or JPQL? Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580285/jpa2-case-insensitive-like-matching-anywhere

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218780/how-to-do-a-like-case-insensitive-and-accent-insensitive-in-oracle-10gr2-and-jpa

Comment: I'm using Criteria queries but I can use JPQL if needed. I know the trick with upper but it's always accent sensitive...

Answer (score 5):

In general there is no standard way to write "accent-insensitive" code, or to compare words for equality while ignoring accents. The whole idea makes very little sense, as different accented characters mean different things in different languages/dialects, and their "plain ascii" substitutions/expansions vary by language. Please don't do this; `resume` and `résumé` are *different words*, and the situation gets even worse when considering any language(s) other than English.

For case-insensitivity you can use `lower(the_col) like lower('%match_expression')` in JPQL. As far as I know `ilike` isn't supported in JPQL, but I have not checked [the standard](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) to verify this. It's fairly readable, so consider just downloading the JPA2 spec and reading it. JPA2 Criteria offers `Restrictions.ilike` for the purpose. Neither will normalize/strip/ignore accented characters.

For stripping accents, etc, you will probably need to use database-engine specific stored functions or native queries. See, eg [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979390/find-all-possible-duplicates-in-two-column-for-lower-case-uppercase-and-special/13010154#13010154), or if you intended to *substitute* accented characters with an unaccented alternative [this PostgreSQL wiki entry](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase) - but again, *please don't do this* except for very limited purposes like finding places where words may've been "unaccented" by misguided software or users.

Answer (score 3):

If the [unaccent extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html) is installed:

```
select unaccent(lower('ãóÊ'));
 unaccent 
----------
 aoe
```

Comment: Yes but with this solution I must make a native query.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I couldn't use database functions. So instead I used a REGEX restriction in my criteria code:

```
searchText = unaccent(searchText);
String expression = "firstName ~* '.*" + searchText + ".*'";
Criterion searchCriteria = Restrictions.sqlRestriction(expression);
```

Then I wrote a function called unaccent to change each character to a or-statement, for example any letter e will become (e|é|è). A query for "hello" will become "h(e|é|è)llo".

Here is the function inspired from this thread [Postgres accent insensitive LIKE search in Rails 3.1 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243322/postgres-accent-insensitive-like-search-in-rails-3-1-on-heroku)

```
private String unaccent(String text) {
    String String charactersProcessed = ""; // To avoid doing a replace multiple times.
    String newText = text.toLowerCase();
    text = newText; // Case statement is expecting lowercase.
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (charactersProcessed.contains(c + "")) {
            continue; // We have already processed this character.
        }
        String replacement = "";
        switch (c) {
        case '1': {
            replacement = "¹";
            break;
        }
        case '2': {
            replacement = "²";
            break;
        }
        case '3': {
            replacement = "³";
            break;
        }
        case 'a': {
            replacement = "á|à|â|ã|ä|å|ā|ă|ą|À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|Ā|Ă|Ą|Æ";
            break;
        }
        case 'c': {
            replacement = "ć|č|ç|©|Ć|Č|Ç";
            break;
        }
        case 'd': {
            replacement = "Đ|Ð";
            break;
        }
        case 'e': {
            replacement = "è|é|ê|ё|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě|È|Ê|Ë|Ё|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě|€";
            break;
        }
        case 'g': {
            replacement = "ğ|Ğ";
            break;
        }
        case 'i': {
            replacement = "ı|ì|í|î|ï|ì|ĩ|ī|ĭ|Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ї|Ì|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ";
            break;
        }
        case 'l': {
            replacement = "ł|Ł";
            break;
        }
        case 'n': {
            replacement = "ń|ň|ñ|Ń|Ň|Ñ";
            break;
        }
        case 'o': {
            replacement = "ò|ó|ô|õ|ö|ō|ŏ|ő|ø|Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö|Ō|Ŏ|Ő|Ø|Œ";
            break;
        }
        case 'r': {
            replacement = "ř|®|Ř";
            break;
        }
        case 's': {
            replacement = "š|ş|ș|ß|Š|Ş|Ș";
            break;
        }
        case 'u': {
            replacement = "ù|ú|û|ü|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|Ù|Ú|Û|Ü|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů";
            break;
        }
        case 'y': {
            replacement = "ý|ÿ|Ý|Ÿ";
            break;
        }
        case 'z': {
            replacement = "ž|ż|ź|Ž|Ż|Ź";
            break;
        }
        }
        if (!replacement.isEmpty()) {
            charactersProcessed = charactersProcessed + c;
            newText = newText.replace(c + "", "(" + c + "|" + replacement + ")");
        }
    }

    return newText;
}
```

Comment: Please, you can use this methode for
 
 public static String unaccent(String text) {
    
      return Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
          
  }

Comment: Thank you, unless I missunderstood the aim of this function `Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")`, it seems that it normalizes a text in the Java code. The need here is to normalize it in PostgreSQL.
The unaccent function I wrote, turn this string `"hello"` to this `"h(è|é|ê|ё|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě|È|Ê|Ë|Ё|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě|€)ll(ò|ó|ô|õ|ö|ō|ŏ|ő|ø|Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö|Ō|Ŏ|Ő|Ø|Œ)"`

Comment: The solution is not optimal, except for the use of native SQL.

Comment: It is possible to use a similar SQL native function, but in my case I couldn't.

Comment: you can trickery by, the convert of the String alphabet by alphabet (one by one) and make a UNION between all the results.

Comment: definetly, dunno why I didn't do that!

Comment: Since I can't use SQL native for most of the search functionalities. accent-insensitive is ignored.